# Amazon EC2 timeout after 30 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, rubber

I deployed a RoR3 application on Amazon EC2 using Rubber.

I have a slow request that takes about 1 minute, but it dies after 30 seconds with the error:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.
```

Does anyone know how to increase the timeout time?

Answer (score 0):

Long running requests are generally not a good idea as you can see. Webservers will generally timeout after 30 seconds of no response from an FCGI application.

You will need to look at fcgi timeout vars for the webserver application your deployment is using.

Comment: where can I look at fcgi vars? I am on Amazon EC2. Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ec2. The setting is related to whatever webserver you are using along with your application. Probably apache or nginx.